# How get Fragment from external Package

Tags: android, android-fragments

A problem: I have MainApp with FrameLayout, were I can easy put MainFragments.class from MainApp. Also I have external package with PlugInApp,  where i have some other PlugInFragment.class. I need put this PlugInFragment.class into MainApp FrameLayout. Seems easy, but it's not.

I can't create fragment object in MainApp from external package. Really need help. Please.

..update..

Ok, I try load PlugiFragment.class using DexClassLoader. Generally, it's working.. I can easy run other classes, or some method of classes, but if I try load PluginFragment, I have error:- unable to resolve superclass for my PlugInFragment, which is extendet from basic Fragment. I think it is because Fragment class is in andrid-support-v4.jar, it's like a private lib, not in main android.jar. I try reload, clean, refresh and other "dancing around" methods - not help at all. Any ideas?

..finish..

Ok, I did it! YEEEH!!

First I stop using Fragment from andrid.support.v4, I use regular Fragment from android.app, this eliminate "unable to resolve superclass error". Then I in my PluginFragment make some changes:

```
      @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    int fragment_layoytRID = 0;

    try {

        //TODO in layout should not use string/color resourses

        fragment_layoytRID = container
                .getContext()
                .getPackageManager()
                .getResourcesForApplication(parkageName)
                .getIdentifier("plagin_fragment", "layout",
                        parkageName);

        Log.w("PLUGIN", "fragment_layoytRID: " + fragment_layoytRID);

    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final XmlResourceParser parser = container.getContext()
            .getPackageManager()
            .getXml(parkageName, fragment_layoytRID, null);


    return inflater.inflate(parser, container, false);


}
```

this is because layout inflaiting from external mainApp.. And it's work.. only problem, that in this case layout did't find @string / @color and else resourses..

Comment: Why? are there problems if you import the **PlugInFragment.class** package and then use it as fragment for the **MainFragments.clas**? what kinds of problems have you find?

Comment: What have you tried already? Are you trying to get the fragment inside the FrameLayout?

Comment: An idea of plugins is use plugin without changing main app, and because i can't add plugin in project, and compile new main app. Main appp is complit - not changeble. plugin is another apk, from plugin into mainapp i can get activity, servis, brodcast, providers, resouses, classnames.. from mainapp i can load plugin actvity with intent - no problem, but is like loading next app with her UI ant funcional.. i'd like load plugin into mainapp - in frameLayout like adding pluginFragment - in this case it still will be mainApp UI and funcional - with extra plagin insaid.. more elegant by me..

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `FrameLayout` you'll need to add the fragment like this:

```
<fragment android:name="your.namespace.PlugInFragment"
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

note that you'll have to change `your.namespace.PlugInFragment` to whatever it's namespace is.